# deaths given definition

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> The "surplus" region of the Soviet  Union was to be detached, its grain and other agricultural produce gathered and diverted to Germany. As discussed at the previous meeting in Berlin, the local population would suffer the consequences. These were now spelt out, with the previous, open estimeate of likely **deaths given definition**. (The Silk Roads)

What does it mean in the sentence "deaths given definition"?

Comment: Hi Mankak, is there a link to the original text? Where did you see this?

Answer (score 1):

No, the 3 words in *deaths given definition* are not to be clustered together and interpreted.

In

> These were now spelt out, with the previous, open estimate of likely deaths given definition.

the phrase "with the previous, open estimate of likely deaths given definition" gives additional information to the main clause before it.

The additional information is that the death figures have become clear.

*definition* could mean

> definition noun (CLEAR QUALITY) C1 [ U ] how clear an image or sound is:
> The photograph lacks definition.

> definition noun (SEEING CLEARLY [ U ]
> the degree to which something can be clearly seen or heard:
> The tape recorded conversation lacked definition – there was too much background noise.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/definition)

Edit

*given definition* roughly means given clarity.

> with the previous, open estimate of likely deaths given clarity

Comment: I see : deaths given definition is not clustered together.  I still dont' figure out how the phrase given definition is  grammatically used or understood.

Comment: I have added more explanations to my answer.

Comment: Is "given" being used as an adjective(past participle)  connected to open estimate?